# How to initialize arrays and vectors in old extension clang and gcc compilers in macOS?

Tags: c++, macos, clang

I have a code in c++. It works in windows, Ubuntu and Fedora.
Now I want to compile it for macOS. I encountered some errors like

```
error: expected expression
error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
```

I have many lines like

```
int A[n][2] = {{2, 5},{2, 6},{3, 4},{3, 7},{4, 3},{5, 2},{6, 2},{7, 3}};
int B[n][2] = {{8, 15},{8, 16},{9, 14},{9, 17},{10, 13},{10, 14},{10, 17},{11, 12},{11, 15},{11, 16},{12, 11},{13, 10},{14, 9},{14, 10},{15, 8},{15, 11},{16, 8},{16, 11},{17, 9},{17, 10}};
```

I searched it is because of the old installed clang and gcc extension in macOS (I am using Mojave 10.14.0)

I do not know what can I do to resolve this problem.

Comment: What is `n` defined as here? Those two lists are different lengths, they can't have the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define these instead like this:

```
int A[][2] = {{2, 5},{2, 6},{3, 4},{3, 7},{4, 3},{5, 2},{6, 2},{7, 3}};
int B[][2] = {{8, 15},{8, 16},{9, 14},{9, 17},{10, 13},{10, 14},{10, 17},{11, 12},{11, 15},{11, 16},{12, 11},{13, 10},{14, 9},{14, 10},{15, 8},{15, 11},{16, 8},{16, 11},{17, 9},{17, 10}};
```

Where `clang` is then happy.

If you specify `n` then you need to ensure the initializer list can fit in the defined structure.